# How do you play a sound on a loop in the background without being interrupted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, multitasking, silent

The following code should play a silent audio clip on a loop to keep an application active in the background:

```
//set sessions ....
.........
//play
audio_player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url error:NULL];
audio_player.numberOfLoops= -1; //always repeat
bool ret = [audio_player play];
```

You press the home button and it plays in background, keeping your application active.

However, when you make a phone call, the player will stop and `[audio_player play]` will return false after that.

So the question is, when in the background, how do you prevent AVAudioPlayer's playback from being interrupted or allow it to resume when interrupted? Otherwise, the application will terminate 10 minutes after the silent audio loop has last played.

I know there is a solution, because there are many alarm clock apps that can run in the background without being affected. I have tested and they are really running in the background.

Can anyone come up with a solution to run in the background without being rejected by the App Store?

Comment: How did you test that they are really running in the background?

Comment: As far as I know your app should not stop after ten min after entering the background.  Read the following links this may help you..  http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9598-avaudioplayer-issue.html https://devforums.apple.com/message/264397#264397 and http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html  And The timer apps cannot be compared with Audio apps.

Comment: This is close to the question [iOS 4 Alarm Clock App with Multitasking Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897946/ios-4-alarm-clock-app-with-multitasking-support), but is asking something slightly different than that. Still, one or two of the answers there might help out here.

Comment: I removed your follow-on language, because it didn't help out the question any. Showing that another application has an alarm that works with being backgrounded doesn't demonstrate that this application was running in the background. They may simply be using local notifications to trigger an alarm at a set time while the application itself is suspended in the background. Section 2.16 of the App Store review guidelines is pretty explicit: "Multitasking apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc."

Answer (score 1):

The answer is once your app is in the background you can not open the audio device again until your app returns to the foreground.