# iPhone alarm using repeated local notifications

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uilocalnotification, alarm

I'm trying to add an in-background alarm clock feature to an app I'm developing.

I have read up on the `UILocalNotification` object and its use, and am aware that it is limited to 30 seconds of audio.

I was thinking of scheduling multiple notifications (say, 5 of them) spaced 30 seconds apart to mimic continuous play, but the problem with this approach is that if the user hits `Close`, I won't be able to cancel any of the subsequent notifications.

As far as I know, it is impossible to remove or hide the `Close` button without hiding the notification entirely (i.e., setting the `alertBody` property to `Nil`).

So, I thought I might use the `repeatInterval` property to cause the notification to pop up every 30 seconds, but it seems that I can only set the interval to one minute or one second, and nothing in between.

The feature is meant to allow the user to choose between music and beeps for alarm audio; it seems I may have found a way to do the beeps - setting the `repeatInterval` to one second, create a second's worth of beeps (which would need to be timed to cleanly repeat) and use that as the notification sound.

However, for the music, this approach limits me to playing 30 seconds of audio, followed by a 30-second gap, followed by 30 seconds of audio, and so on.

I know that there is no straightforward solution here, from my reading of other posts and resources; no third-party app has access to the same functionality as the built-in alarm clock.  I am hoping that someone has found a workaround or thinks of something really clever.

UPDATE: I have found that the `repeatInterval` doesn't help me in this case, as I can't cancel the repetitions without launching the app.

For the time being I have decided not to use a notification as an alarm per se, but have changed the feature to be a reminder (more along the lines of what the notification is intended for).

If I come up with a way to implement user-friendly, reliable alarm functionality to an app, I will update this post.

Comment: "multiple notifications (say, 5 of them) spaced 30 seconds apart to mimic continuous play" - it just won't work this way 'cause LocalNotification precision limited to one minute...

Comment: Consider using background execution in your app. As far as I know apps can play music in background.

Comment: Here's an example of how someone built the local notification background alarm you allude to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4197215/1264925

Comment: @Oner: I know about the one-minute precision, as I describe in my post.

Comment: @Oner: I do use background execution to play music, but not as part of this alarm feature; I need something to trigger the alarm audio playing while the app is in the background, hence the use of notifications.

Comment: @RyanTwomey thank you for the suggestion, but that solution has the problem that if the user taps Close, the subsequent notifications can't be canceled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you cannot accomplish this..reason being as you stated the 'Close' button. You won't be getting any call back in the app if Close button is tapped. Further even if you present notifications every 30 seconds, then there will be multiple notifications on the screen which user has to view or close. So the user experience will be crappy. I would recommended making it clear to the users that they can not set alarm with a custom sound more than 30 seconds.

Comment: @bschnur how can you set callback? would you update any example or answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857236/trigger-local-notifications-automatically-daily-on-dynamic-time-given-in-arrays